# Chrome Console: 2670.82 + 202.38 = 2873.2000000000003?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

> 2670.82+202.38

`2873.2000000000003`

Try it for yourself. I have no idea what's going on here. Is this a quark of Javascript? The Chrome Browser?

Comment: That's how floating numbers do work in JS :) In all programming languages, actually. Floating operations are calculated with some precision, and sometimes this precision brings surprises.

Comment: Thanks for linking to that other post. I didn't even know what to search for!

Comment: A simpler example case: 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004